# jquery live tabIndex

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a jQuery statement that's working fine. How would I re-write it in `.live`?

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {

    $(':input:enabled:visible, a:enabled:visible, span.ValidatorClass').each
    (function(i, e) { $(e).attr('tabindex', i) });


  });
```

The reason I need this is I hide/show elements sometimes using `.show` and `.hide` and when that happens I need to reset tab order for the elements that appear/disappear.

Comment: if you're only showing and hiding the elements you can set the tab index anyway - it will be ignored hidden elements, so the value from `$(document).ready` should be correct. What isn't working for you then?

Comment: If I do .show newly appeared elements do not have tab index set since they were not visible when this page loaded, so they are skipped over when tabbing.

Comment: Well, of course, because you're selection `:visible`. What if you selected `:input, a, span.ValidatorClass` ? (by the way, can a `<span>` have tab indexes?)

Comment: That seems to be working even for elements that hidden now, thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing and hiding elements raises no events as far as I know, so `live` won't help you here.

However, since you don't add new elements nor reorder them, you can set the correct `tabindex` right from the start. The browser will ignore hidden or disabled elements anyway. Run your code without the `:visible` and `enabled` filters:

```
$(':input, a, span.ValidatorClass')
 .each(function(i, e) { $(e).attr('tabindex', i) });
```